# Where is the member and owner group membership held in the O365 group that's created for SharePoint teams site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, administration, groups

I have created a SharePoint teams site: test123

As part of this I have got a group called test123 along with mailbox test123@companyname.com

In the SharePoint site, when I click on add members button and add an user and choose either owner or member in the drop down, then this user isn't showing up in the SharePoint permissions under the memeber or owner group. Where exactly is this assignment getting stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add any users from add members option from SharePoint site (as shown in below image), those users will be added to associated M365 group owners/members and not in SharePoint groups (owners/members) directly:

[image]

Check this thread once for understanding how M365 groups and SharePoint groups are connected: [What does it mean by "Team sites use Microsoft 365 Groups for permissions. Communication sites use SharePoint groups"?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304893/what-does-it-mean-by-team-sites-use-microsoft-365-groups-for-permissions-commu/304899#304899).

If you don't want to add users in M365 groups and want to add them ONLY in SharePoint site, you can add those from advanced SharePoint permissions settings:

1. Go to SharePoint site
2. Click on Settings (gear) icon from top right corner
3. Select "Site permission" --> "Advanced permissions settings".
4. It will take you to SharePoint permissions page where you can see "SharePoint groups"
5. Click on any SharePoint group name
6. You will see "New" option to add users to SharePoint groups:

   [image]

**Note**: Using these steps, users will be added to ONLY SharePoint permissions. Hence M365 group related resources like mailbox, planner, etc. will not be shared with these users.

---

**Additional**:

You can manage M365 groups and membership from The Microsoft 365 admin center if you have necessary permissions in the tenant. Check: [Manage Microsoft 365 groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/enterprise/manage-microsoft-365-groups?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

Comment: I beleive this is valid only for team site, and not for communication site, correct?

Comment: Also do only owner and member have access to the mailbox, or even the visitors have access to the mailbox? I think answer is only owner or member because there is no visitor concept to the O365 group. Correct?

Comment: Both team site and communication site permissions can be managed using SharePoint groups. Even if team site is connected with M365 group.

Comment: Correct, only Owners/Members of M365 group will have access to mailbox - no visitor concept for M365 groups.