# Which users have access to the additional items that come with the team site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, administration, groups

Along with a SharePoint team site I get a lot of things like O365 group, mailbox, planner, etc.

But who exactly has access to this mailbox, planner, etc?

Is it the SharePoint owner, member, visitor or a combination of these that have got the access to the things like mailbox, planner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a SharePoint team site connected with M365 group, it creates a M365 group in your tenant.

M365 group owners and members will have access to related resources like mailbox, planner, etc.

SharePoint groups (owners/members/visitors) will not have access on these resources automatically unless they are owner/member of M365 group.

Check this thread once for understanding how M365 groups and SharePoint groups are connected: [What does it mean by "Team sites use Microsoft 365 Groups for permissions. Communication sites use SharePoint groups"?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304893/what-does-it-mean-by-team-sites-use-microsoft-365-groups-for-permissions-commu/304899#304899).

Check below Microsoft documentations for more understanding:

1. [Sharing and permissions in the SharePoint modern experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/modern-experience-sharing-permissions?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
2. [Planning Permissions with Group-based SharePoint Sites... when you're used to Regular SharePoint Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/community/permission-model-differences?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)